# When I submit the form in childComponent my page is refreshing in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have a quiz application that you can choose amount of question,difficulty etc.After submitting you will directed to quiz screen.I have a parent component called **App** and child component called **StartScreen**. I want to change some states in child component and submit them.After summitting I will see the quiz testing screen.In parent component I have a state called **start**.When I change **start** from **false** to **true** I will see the quiz screen.My problem is that, when I change **start** to **true** in child component it refresh the page.So I cant see quiz screen

Parent component

```
import './App.css';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import QuestionGrid from './components/QuestionGrid';
import StartScreen from './components/StartScreen';
function App() {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState("10");
  const [category, setCategory] = useState("23");
  const [difficulty, setDifficulty] = useState('easy');
  const [start, setStart] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      `https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=${amount}&category=${category}&difficulty=${difficulty}&type=multiple`
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setItems(result.results);
        },

        (error) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setError(error);
        }
      );
  }, [amount,category,difficulty]);
  console.log(error);
  console.log(isLoaded);

  return start === true ? (
    <div className="App">
      <QuestionGrid isLoaded={isLoaded} items={items} />
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div>
      <StartScreen amount={(e)=>setAmount(e)} category={(e)=>setCategory(e)} difficulty={(e)=>setDifficulty(e)}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my child component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function startScreen(props) {


    
  return (
    <section className="mt-3">
      <header className="text-center">
        <h2>Welcome to QUIZ</h2>
      </header>
      <div className="col-sm-6 m-auto">
          <form action="">
        <input
        onChange={(e)=>(props.amount(e.target.value))}
        placeholder="Select amount of questions"
          type="number"
          name="trivia_amount"
          id="trivia_amount"
          class="form-control"
          min="1"
          max="50"
        ></input>
        <select
          class="form-select form-select-md "
          aria-label=".form-select-lg example"
          onChange={(e)=>(props.category(e.target.value))}

        >
          <option selected>Select the category</option>
          <option value="any">Any Category</option>
          <option value="9">General Knowledge</option>
          <option value="10">Entertainment: Books</option>
          <option value="11">Entertainment: Film</option>
          <option value="12">Entertainment: Music</option>
          <option value="13">Entertainment: Musicals &amp; Theatres</option>
          <option value="14">Entertainment: Television</option>
          <option value="15">Entertainment: Video Games</option>
          <option value="16">Entertainment: Board Games</option>
          <option value="17">Science &amp; Nature</option>
          <option value="18">Science: Computers</option>
          <option value="19">Science: Mathematics</option>
          <option value="20">Mythology</option>
          <option value="21">Sports</option>
          <option value="22">Geography</option>
          <option value="23">History</option>
          <option value="24">Politics</option>
          <option value="25">Art</option>
          <option value="26">Celebrities</option>
          <option value="27">Animals</option>
          <option value="28">Vehicles</option>
          <option value="29">Entertainment: Comics</option>
          <option value="30">Science: Gadgets</option>
          <option value="31">Entertainment: Japanese Anime &amp; Manga</option>
          <option value="32">
            Entertainment: Cartoon &amp; Animations
          </option>{' '}
        </select>
        <select
          class="form-select form-select-md mb-5"
          aria-label=".form-select-lg example"
          onChange={(e)=>(props.difficulty(e.target.value))}

        >
          <option selected>Select the difficulty</option>
          <option value="any">Any Difficulty</option>
          <option value="easy">Easy</option>
          <option value="medium">Medium</option>
          <option value="hard">Hard</option>
        </select>
       

        <button type="submit" value="true" className="btn btn-danger col-sm-4 m-auto d-flex justify-content-center"  onClick={(e)=>(alert(e.target.value))}>
          Submit
        </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

Comment: Just add this to your form `onSubmit={(e)=>e.preventDefault()}`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop page from reloading by using `preventDefault`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';

export default function startScreen(props) {
    const handleSubmit = useCallback((event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        alert(event.target.value)
    }, [])

    return (
        <section className="mt-3">
            <header className="text-center">
                <h2>Welcome to QUIZ</h2>
            </header>
            <div className="col-sm-6 m-auto">
                <form action="">
                    <input
                        onChange={(e) => (props.amount(e.target.value))}
                        placeholder="Select amount of questions"
                        type="number"
                        name="trivia_amount"
                        id="trivia_amount"
                        class="form-control"
                        min="1"
                        max="50"
                    ></input>
                    <select
                        class="form-select form-select-md "
                        aria-label=".form-select-lg example"
                        onChange={(e) => (props.category(e.target.value))}

                    >
                        <option selected>Select the category</option>
                        <option value="any">Any Category</option>
                        <option value="9">General Knowledge</option>
                        <option value="10">Entertainment: Books</option>
                        <option value="11">Entertainment: Film</option>
                        <option value="12">Entertainment: Music</option>
                        <option value="13">Entertainment: Musicals &amp; Theatres</option>
                        <option value="14">Entertainment: Television</option>
                        <option value="15">Entertainment: Video Games</option>
                        <option value="16">Entertainment: Board Games</option>
                        <option value="17">Science &amp; Nature</option>
                        <option value="18">Science: Computers</option>
                        <option value="19">Science: Mathematics</option>
                        <option value="20">Mythology</option>
                        <option value="21">Sports</option>
                        <option value="22">Geography</option>
                        <option value="23">History</option>
                        <option value="24">Politics</option>
                        <option value="25">Art</option>
                        <option value="26">Celebrities</option>
                        <option value="27">Animals</option>
                        <option value="28">Vehicles</option>
                        <option value="29">Entertainment: Comics</option>
                        <option value="30">Science: Gadgets</option>
                        <option value="31">Entertainment: Japanese Anime &amp; Manga</option>
                        <option value="32">
                            Entertainment: Cartoon &amp; Animations
          </option>{' '}
                    </select>
                    <select
                        class="form-select form-select-md mb-5"
                        aria-label=".form-select-lg example"
                        onChange={(e) => (props.difficulty(e.target.value))}

                    >
                        <option selected>Select the difficulty</option>
                        <option value="any">Any Difficulty</option>
                        <option value="easy">Easy</option>
                        <option value="medium">Medium</option>
                        <option value="hard">Hard</option>
                    </select>


                    <button type="submit" value="true" className="btn btn-danger col-sm-4 m-auto d-flex justify-content-center" onClick={handleSubmit}>
                        Submit
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>
    );
}
```